# How do I set custom text for the navigation buttons in Jquery anythingslider?

Tags: anythingslider

I have recently started using Jquery anythingslider and I'm loving it till now.

I just wanted whether it is possible to change the default text which appears on the navigation buttons (1,2 etc..) to some custom text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`navigationFormatter` option](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Navigation-options#wiki-navigationformatter):

```
$('#slider2').anythingSlider({
  // Format navigation labels with text
  navigationFormatter : function(index, panel){
    return ['Recipe', 'Quote', 'Image', 'Quote #2', 'Image #2'][index - 1];
  }
});
```